# What is the best way to generate German paraphrases?

Tags: transformer, natural-language-understanding, seq2seq, natural-language-generation

What is the best method to generate German paraphrases? The state-of-the-art are seq2seq transformer models, like T5, but they only work for English sentences. I found the multilingual MT5 model, but how do you fine-tune this for German?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE. Could you please tell us more about your problem? What exactly is this model supposed to do, i.e. what do you mean by "paraphrase"? Do you mean a model that would be able to rewrite a sentence in another way but leaving its meaning intact?

Comment: The best way to do that is to ask a German to paraphrase it for you :P

Comment: Probably the exact same model but trained on German data instead of English.